# During Pod Installation `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` is not used in any concrete target

Tags: afnetworking, cocoapods, osx-elcapitan, xcode7.3, afnetworking-3

Recently I've installed cocoapods v 1.0.0 in my mac successfully, I am trying to install `'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'` dependency in my pod file of my project directory. which I've created successfully, by putting following code in my pod file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
```

but when I write `pod install` in terminal it giving me following error

```
[!] The dependency `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` is not used in any concrete target.
```

could anyone suggest me why I am getting this error & how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After submitting this question, I further explored its solution & come to know at "https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html" that I should write simply this code in my podefile

```
target 'MyApp' do


pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

instead of above which I found at github AFNetworking official dependency installation guide. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

But I am curious about why the official AFNetworking method does not works for its installation in my project? could anyone answer it please?

anyway Thanks to cocoapods official website.